# Why this first post review for a post which was created two weeks ago?

Tags: bug, review, new-users

Today, I got [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3699913/446262) at the Mathematics Stack Exchange First Posts review queue. How is it possible that an answer posted 14 days ago by a user who

- has already posted 25 answers
- has been around for two weeks
- whose reputation is 429

is considered a first post? Since it was not an audit, I suspect that it is due to a bug.

Comment: Looking at the users history, that was their first post, what they did after is irrelevant https://math.stackexchange.com/users/794841/nitin-tomar?tab=answers&sort=newest This is not a bug, the post just got stuck in the queue for a while, I can't say why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to confirm with one of the Mathematics ♦ moderators to know for sure, but I suspect the following happened: they've posted a question or answer *before* May 31st, that was reviewed, but the post has meanwhile been deleted, less than 24 hours ago. Now the system sees *this* is their first post, which hasn't been reviewed, and creates a review item for it.

For a user who is already so familiar with Stack Exchange as this one, it's unnecessary, but there are many cases of users who *don't* get it, and it's a Good Thing™ that (some of) their subsequent posts are reviewed as well.